# C++ greater than check return wrong result

Tags: c++

I want  to check  greater than using c++, but it return wrong result.
When I call `cal()` it return false. But it should return true actually.
I am using max int value for variable then why this happening ?

```
int cal(int x, int y) {
    return y+1 > x;
}

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    n=m= INT_MAX;
    cout<<cal(n,m)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output : `0`

But it should be `1`. I don't use overflow integer for variable then why ?

Is there any way to check like this ?

Comment: Check for not lower or equal. `it return wrong result` - what result would that be? How is it wrong? `I want to check greater than using c++` you want to check if one variable is greater then the other, or you want to check if one variable is greater then the other to at least 1?

Comment: @KamilCuk Why I can't use greater than ?

Comment: For a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, `2147483647 + 1` will overflow and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You could do `return y > x-1;` to fix this specific value comparison but it just moves the problem to the other end of the `int` range.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't use overflow integer for variable then why ?

Comment: There are many problems with your question: 1) **What** is it that you want to check? 2) **Why** are you using constants like `2147483647` instead of `INT_MAX` which is much clearer to read and implementation-defined. 3) Avoid using maximum values of integer data-types unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Ruks what is the difference between INT_MAX and 2147483647 ?

Comment: `INT_MAX` is defined by the C++ specification to always be the max value of a signed `int`. `2147483647` is a [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) which might not be equal to `INT_MAX` on some platforms. You could also use [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max).

Comment: @Ruks I used INT_MAX  it results same

Comment: `INT_MAX` is `2147483647` on your system. Of course, the result is the same. What do you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of your program is undefined because it depends on the size of `int`. In your case `2147483647` probably is the size `INT_MAX`. That means that `y+1` overflows and the result is undefined.

In C++ numbers have a fixed size. In your case `int` has 4 byte/32 bit. If you add `1` to the largest number, the result can't be a larger number. Overflow occurs. The result of signed overflow is undefined.

You can fix your function with:

```
#include <cstdint>

int cal(std::int32_t x, std::int32_t y) {
    return static_cast<std::int64_t>(y)+1 > x;
}
```

Now the value can't overflow. You could also include a check:

```
int cal(int x, int y) {
    if (y == INT_MAX) return 1;
    return y+1 > x;
}
```

Comment: `y+1` is overflowed but in c++ variable data can not be overflow,  I don't use overflow integer for variable.

Comment: @MivaleAndres I don't understand what you mean. `2147483647` is the largest possible value. If add 1, you get overflow. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: @MivaleAndres Arithmetic overflow is UB. If you had `2147483647 + 1` then the compiler would use the next larger type (`long` or `long long`) but since you have an `int` variable `y` the whole operation is done using `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why Arithmetic overflow doesn't give any error give show wrong result

Comment: @MivaleAndres You don't need to store it in a variable. Your program has to store the result of `y+1` somewhere in memory.

Comment: @MivaleAndres the act of addition causes undefined behaviour,  not the act of trying to store the result

Comment: @ThomasSablik thats means c++ create temp storage for `y+1`, then why it can't use automatically like other data type which can store this value

Comment: @MivaleAndres C++ follows the philosophy: "You don't pay, what you don't need". More memory is a cost. If you want it, you have to order it. If you want more memory, convert it to `long`. How could the compiler know at compile time that you will need more memory at runtime?

Comment: @MivaleAndres c++ consider `y+1`  as interger and store it, you can use long.